# Line break the string when passing props to React's stateless component

Tags: reactjs

I have a stateless component that will in the future group two of the Option stateless components:

```
const Grouped = () => {
    const options = [
        {
            header: "Create new Lamborghini",
            body:   "Generate a new Lamborghini",
            button: "Generate"
        },

        {
            header: "Get Lamborghini",
            body:   "Getz it",
            button: "Get it"
        }
    ];

    return (
    <div>
        <Option {...options[0]} />
    </div>);
};

export default HomeOptionsGrouped;
```

Option looks like this:

```
const Option = ({header, body, button}) => (
    <div className="option-container">
        <img className="option-modal" src={OptionModal} alt="Option Modal"/>
        <h5>{header}</h5>
        <p className="option-body">{body}</p>
        <p className="option-button">{button}</p>
    </div>
);

export default Option;
```

Problem I have is that I want to line break header say after the word new, and body after word new. But when I add '\n' to the strings in the Grouped component, I am still getting everything on one line. I do not want to set the innerHTML and pass the strings. What is the workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

insted of being a string, your header value should look like:

```
<span>Create new<br />Lamborghini</span>
```

the same applies to a body value, if you wish the same effect.

Comment: I prefer this answer because I can nest this span inside h5 in option and set className in option! Nice

Comment: You can use `<React.Fragment>` too if you are using React 16.2. See https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html

Answer (score 1):

Just change your `header` to a React element, as you can nest them within `<h5>` and `<p>`:

```
header: <div>Create new<br />Lamborghini</div>,
```

Comment: isn't it a bit weird that I will be setting classes for these React components in Grouped even though they relate to Option?

Comment: Why do you need to set classes for them? If so, you can turn it into full-fledge component: `Header: ({ className }) => <div className={className}>...</div>` then pass the className with `<h5><Header className="something" /><h5>`. Alternatively clone the `header` element in `Option` and add `className` prop to it.

Comment: Option is like a box with descriptions and stuff, and I am positioning these elements (header, body, button) in it with css

Comment: using `<div`> won't require you to set `className` within `Grouped` too, can you show an image of what layout you are trying to achieve and what layout you ended up with if you don't set `className` within `Grouped`?